# Love for a parent (father)

Tags: single-word-requests

The love for one's children is *parental*. For siblings -- *sisterly* or *brotherly*.

How would one refer to the feelings towards one's parents, particularly -- the father?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Love for one's parents is [**filial**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/filial).

[**Storge**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storge) - familial love - denotes instinctual affection, such as the love of a parent towards offspring and vice versa.

**Xiao** 孝 (filial piety) "consists of reverent, sincere, self-sacrificing, and unconditional care for one’s parents while they are alive and after their death. [It] is one of the basic values of Chinese traditional culture in general and the basis for the development of the moral person in Confucian ethics in particular." - *L. POŠKAITĖ (Asian Studies II (XVIII), 1 (2014), p.99)*

I don't know of a word specifically denoting 'towards one's father'.

Comment: Yep, "filial" is the word that denotes feelings directed from child to parent.  "Paternal" is the other way around -- from father toward child.

Comment: Is it not remarkable, that "_paternal_" and "_parental_" are anagrams of each other?

Comment: Very remarkable!

Answer (score -1):

**[agape](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agape)**

The term "agape" denotes the highest form of love, which is generally exemplified as the love one feels for God (i.e., Heavenly Father) or one's own parents (i.e., earthly father and earthly mother), the love for one's mother probably being the most salient of those examples for most people, the example they can best get their arms around to understand exactly what it conveys.  This is in contrast to other types of love, like "philia," which is brotherly love, or "philautia," which is self-love.